# Weird URL when using my Asp.Net site

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I currently have a Asp.net site running, say on `http://www.example.org/`. When I go to `http://www.example.org/`, the URL in the broswer bar changes from `http://www.example.org/Default.aspx` to `http://www.example.org/(S(atwnw1wd3kycxgocvovs1yui))/Default.aspx`

What is happening here? is this a problem with my IIS 8.0 server setup? or is it my Asp.Net project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your web.config has following setting:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx